# Elastic Search - Multiple index with Field map

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need to search multiple indices along with its field maps.

For example I want to query a string, in

> ```
> field1 with index1
>
> field2 with index2
> ```

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([eshost])
req_string = {
  "size":1000,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "string to be searched",
      "fields": ["field1","field2"],
    }
  }
}

res = es.search(index='index1,index2', body=req_string)
```

Is it possible to do it ?
If yes please guide with some links. Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [_index field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html#mapping-index-field), when querying across multiple indexes.

> The _index field allows matching on the index a document was indexed
> into. Its value is accessible in certain queries and aggregations, and
> when sorting or scripting

Adding a working example with index data,search query, and search result.

**Index Data:**

```
PUT/ index1/_doc/1
    {
        "name": "Hello"
    }

PUT/ index2/_doc/1
{
    "name": "Hello World"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "_index": [
                            "index1",
                            "index2"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "simple_query_string": {
                        "query": "hello",
                        "fields": [
                            "name",
                            "title"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "index2",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.4700036,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Hello World"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "index1",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.2876821,
    "_source": {
      "title": "Hello"
    }
  }
]
```

**Updated Search Query:**

The below search query will search for `title` field only in `index1` and `name` field only in `index2`

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "filter": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "_index": [
                                        "index1"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "query": "hello",
                                    "fields": [
                                        "title"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "filter": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "_index": [
                                        "index2"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "query": "hello",
                                    "fields": [
                                        "name"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually if both indexes have "name" and "title", will it consider index1 with name and index2 with title ??

Comment: @VivekAnanthan it will not consider `name` from `index2` and `title` from `index1`. The above search query just searches for matching document in the given indexes. But if you want such a use case where index should be mapped to a particular field, then you can go through my updated query (using multiple bool clauses)

Comment: @VivekAnanthan did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)